# How to implement package install suggestion on Debian?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian, autocomplete, command-not-found

I have noticed that while on Ubuntu, if I type the following:

```
mc
```

and it isn't installed, I get the message below:

```
The program 'mc' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install mc
```

However in Debian, that is not available. It just gives a "-bash: /usr/bin/mc: No such file or directory" message. How can I implement the same functionality in bash command line on Debian? Yes, I know that if it is package suggestion that I want, I can simply do a regex search using *apt-cache search*. However I was hoping for the simpler suggestion immediately on typing the name of the program.

As per discussions, the functionality is provided by the package ***command-not-found***. However even after installing it, and also installing bash-completion package, this isn't available on the Debian bash shell.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The reason that installing `command-not-found` did not start providing suggestions for non-installed packages was that I had missed a small notification from dpkg as part of the install.

One is supposed to run the command `update-command-not-found` immediately after running `apt-get install command-not-found`. In fact dpkg prompts for running this command.

Comment: I also had to run `apt-get update` before running `update-command-not-found` then either open a new bash session or `source /etc/bash.bash.rc`.

Comment: I did an `apt update` before `apt install command-not-found` then the `update-command-not-found`, and then started a new shell, but found I needed another `apt update` and maybe `update-command-not-found` before it started working.

Answer (score 10):

The debian package seems to be incomplete. The README says that you should source `/etc/bash_command_not_found` in your `.bashrc`. Strangely that file is not included in the package.

The debian [`command-not-found` package](http://packages.debian.org/command-not-found)  is based on the [ubuntu package](https://launchpad.net/command-not-found). The ubuntu package seems to be more complete in that regard.

Content of the ubuntu version of [bash_command_not_found](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~command-not-found-developers/command-not-found/trunk/view/head:/bash_command_not_found):

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  if  [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
     /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1" 
     return $?
  else
     return 127
  fi        
}
```

Add those lines to your `~/.bashrc` (or `/etc/bash.bashrc`) and the `command-not-found` feature should work.

Comment: The README is incorrect, Debian does not use that file. The handler is included in /etc/bash.bashrc (at least in Debian 9) which is run automatically by Bash interactive shells when they start up.

Comment: Installing the `command-not-found` package (version 0.2.38-4 from debian.org) to MX Linux (Debian 9 Stretch base) did not modify /etc/bash.bashrc and subsequently didn't work until adding the lines in this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this problem by:

First install command-not-found

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install command-not-found
```

After that

```
sudo update-command-not-found
sudo apt update
```

Comment: This seems to me like the most correct answer.

Comment: Correct answer was posted in 2013. This is a copy paste from it, 7 years later

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure if update is working correctly or if your command-not-found is installed properly, just use

```
sudo apt reinstall command-not-found
```

then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and lastly, before updating command-not-found use terminal as a root, by

```
sudo -i
```

You'll see that your hostname (part of the phrase before @) changed to "root"
Then write this command

```
update-command-not-found
```

no need to write "sudo" here, because you're already recognized as a root and sudo didn't work here for me anyway. Only root access did. Nonetheless it should work fine now.

Answer (score -1):

In Debian, after installation of command-not-found, you should issues this command:

```
apt-get update
```

or

```
apt-file update
```

please note that the command `update-command-not-found` doesn't affect. Also you should logout and login again to make the new command-not-found shell scripts in /etc/profile run. Or you can run/source them manually.