# Fedora command-line installation proposals

Tags: command-line, fedora

How to force Fedora command-line to give me proposals for installation of package when a missing command is typed?

Now when I type `git` the command-line tells me :

```
-bash: git: command not found
```

Before it gave me proposal (something like this):

```
Command not found. Install package 'git' to provide command 'git'? [N/y]
```

I made a clean installation of Fedora 24 and obviously this feature is missing. I tried to `dnf install command-not-found` but it couldn't find the package. What should I do to bring this feature back?

Comment: And http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74873/117549 ?

Comment: I see, maybe we should extend the other answers with the Fedora-specific prefix for the `command-not-found` package: `PackageKit-`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install `PackageKit-command-not-found` package:

```
dnf install PackageKit-command-not-found
```

It is fine to check its config `/etc/PackageKit/CommandNotFound.conf` for some details (it's well documented), but default config should be enough.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. After installation it's necessary to `log off` and then to `log on` to activate the proposals.